# Tenses in the relative clause with "would"

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

**[SOURCE](http://philosopher.io/Where-I-m-At-When-It-Comes-To-Animal-Ethics)**

> Certainly I don’t want to tie it to simple possession of a central
>   nervous system, for that would rule out lobsters and octopi and many
>   other things I think **we would generally accept were clearly sentient**.

Would it be wrong to put it **we would generally accept *are* clearly sentient**?

Comment: The past tense is not appropriate here. Your _"are"_ is much better. (Also, the plural of _octopus_ is _octopus**es**_, not "octopi". The word "octopi" does not exist in any language. The root of the word is Greek, not Latin. This is a common error on the part of writers who wish to appear to be learned, but who know no Latin. (In Greek the plural would be _octopodes_.)

Comment: I knew about "octopi" problem but didn't want to distract a reader from my main question. BTW, octopi is step by step encroaching upon octopuses, making it into even respected dictionaries.

Comment: True. Well, _octopi_ it is, then, along with _platypi_. Pity the classical languages aren't taught anymore, but language evolves.

Comment: Well, I've got 20 en-en dictionaries installed and only specialized "usage" dictionaries mention the problem. Many others, including Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th Ed., American Heritage Dictionary 4th Ed.,Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary 11th Ed.,Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary, cite octopi as the legitimate plural. Collins English Dictionary 8th Ed. and Collins Cobuild Advanced Learner’s English Dictionary don't but provide no further explanation.

Comment: They all present _octopi_ as **a** plural, many as a second option, but I assume that eventually it will become the first option, as Latin and Greek sink slowly in the West. OED has: "Inflections:  Plural _octopuses, octopi, (rare) octopodes..._" It's an honest error, maybe, since the word was borrowed by Latin from the Greek.

Comment: I really don't know but it seems to me that using octopi (let alone octopodes) beyond scientific papers might sound a bit snobbish. Just a guess ))

Comment: Well, if someone uses _octopi_ in an attempt to appear erudite, they are hoist by their own petard.